# Access variables from another class without having to pass them directly when calling a page in my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart

does anyone know how i can access variables from another class without having to pass them directly when calling a page like this "Pagetwo(data:data)" because dont need the page to open i just need the variables, i tried simply importing the class i wanted and accessing it like this " var newdata = otherclass.data" but i keep getting the error "Instance member 'data' can't be accessed using static access", not sure what to do next,been researching for a while now

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it

1. Global (which is not recommend)
2. state management technique (which is recommend)

there are many state management technique are there:

```
InheritedWidget

Scoped Model

ProviderScope

Redux

BLOC

RxVMS

MVC

rebloc

Dartea

MobX

Statelessly/Reactivity

var_widget

fish-redux

Flutter Hooks

Provider

AsyncRedux

OSAM

Get

Momentum

state_notifier (by creator of provider)

cubit (by creator of bloc)

maestro

meowchannel

no_bloc

blocstar

mvcprovider

states_rebuilder
```

The most popular state management technique is provider, bloc, redux, getX, InheritedWidget.
if you need an example then please let me know.

Comment: I am giving you an example of a `provider`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make viewModel in the `provider` where every variable is there.

```
class BaseModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  int variable = 0;
  notifyChange() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

let's say if you have two classes and you want to access the same variable which is in ViewModel so you can use provider `singleton` for that.

This is the first-class which is on one page.

```
class BookDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final BookModel bookModel = Provider.of(context);
    print(bookModel.variable);
   }
}
```

This is the second class which is another page.

```
class BookDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final BookModel bookModel = Provider.of(context);
    print(bookModel.variable);
   }
}
```

Comment: for more information, you can go with https://pub.dev/packages/provider.